# Actionscript NetStream.play drops port in relative URLs

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, http, netstream, port-number

the current page my flash application is running from is http://localhost:3000/.  I'm trying to play a video using NetStream.play(relativeURL) by using a relative URL (e.g. "myVideo.flv"), but when I look at the actual request made by actionscript, it's dropping the port number.  (e.g. http://localhost/myVideo.flv).

Is there something I can do on the flash side to make this work?  Is anyone else having this problem?

Comment: In your question your sample is "myVideo.flv", but the request is to "myVideo.swf". Is this a typo?

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/NetConnection.html#connect%28%29 <-- did you take a look at this?

Comment: Whoops -- corrected the swf/flv discrepency -- thanks.  Lior, I just looked at the NetConnection.connect() method, but I'm not really sure what I should be looking for.  I see that there are restrictions on commonly reserved ports, but I couldn't find any specifics on this...

Comment: I'm just calling mNetConnection.connect(null), as in many of the ActionScript sample snippets.  I know that according to the docs, this is only for a video on the local computer, but it seems to work okay for remote videos in all other cases (other than this port issue one)

Comment: Relative URLs are very weird in NetStream.play, so I wouldn't be surprised this is a bug of some sort... does it works with an absolute URL? (http://localhost:3000/myVideo.flv)

Comment: Yep... haven't tried without the protocol, but with protocol, hostname, and port, + path it works fine.  (e.g. http://localhost:3000/myVideo.flv)

Answer (score 0):

`NetConnection.connect( null )` is used to play progressive video and has nothing to do with whether the (video)file's hosted locally or remotely. If you would want to play streaming video, you'd pass in the host url of the streaming service. 
And yes, if you use a relative URL the port is dropped. I suppose some kind of 'translation' from relative to absolute is done, using the location of the embedding html file, which wouldn't be containing the port number, I think? Have you tried passing the absolute url (with port number) as the 'base' parameter to the .swf?